# Parameter transfer does not work in the Angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

The page has a calendar from Angular - md-datepicker with the following parameters:

```
<md-datepicker
   tzoned-date
   ng-model="objt.datesince"
   timezone="objt.timezone"
   ng-required>
</md-datepicker>
```

directives code:

```
.directive('tzonedDate', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        var toView = function (val) {
            var momentd = moment.utc(val).utcOffset(attrs.timezone);
            return new Date(momentd.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        };

        var toModel = function (val) {
            return moment(val);
        };

        ngModel.$formatters.unshift(toView);
        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(toModel);
    }
};
})
```

Actually the problem is that the time parameter in the directive is passed normally, but the time zone parameter is always passed empty (I tried write **timezone = "{{objt.timezone}}"**) The result is the same.

Comment: Try adding   scope: {
                                timezone: "=",
        },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$scope.$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval):

```
.directive('tzonedDate', function () {    
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {        

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(toView);
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(toModel);

            function toView(val) {
                //var momentd = moment.utc(val).utcOffset(attrs.timezone);
                //Use scope.$eval
                var timezone = scope.$eval(attrs.timezone);
                var momentd = moment.utc(val).utcOffset(timezone);
                return new Date(momentd.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            }

            function toModel(val) {
                return moment(val);
            }
        }
    };    
})
```

Use `$eval` to evaluate the the timezone attribute as an Angular Expression in the context of the directive scope.